# Oracle ADF : Page fragment not showing using taskflow inside region

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I have dragged and dropped a task flow containing a View with input texts from the Data Control to the main page. Everytimes i run in , the region is blank, the page fragment isn't displayed

```
<f:facet>
<af:region value="#{bindings.myTaskFlow.regionModel}" id="r9">
</f:facet>
```

What could be the cause ?

Comment: What is your exact JDev version? Can you show us what's inside the region, please?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. The version of Jdeveloper is 11.1.2.2.0 Unfortunatly I cannot share much because i work on a remote computer from which i can't Copy-Paste. The region contains a Task flow, the task flow has only one view which is a page fragment  juste containing texts

Comment: Not much to work with. We need to understand the layout and the layout containers used in the fragment. The blank page points to a problem with the layout containers. I guess the region is there but it's 0 or 1 pixel in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to either that taskflow is not secured in Jazn or current user does not have access to that taskflow even though it is secured.